# onclick search box appears trying to add auto focus

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, onclick

I have a button in home.php:

```
<p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success search" onclick="search(this)">Get started today</button></p>
```

That I turn into a search box using search-box.js:

```
var html =
'<body>\
  <div id="the-basics" class="bs-example" autofocus>\
      <input style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead tt-input" placeholder="National Parks" type="text" autofocus>\
      <pre style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: -apple-system; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; text-transform: none;" aria-hidden="true">a</pre>\
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;" class="tt-menu tt-empty">\
      <div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-parks">\
      </div></div>\
  </div>\
</body>';


 function search(elem) {
  elem.outerHTML = html;
 };
```

I've been trying to do an auto focus with another file called autofocus.jquery.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$.autofocus();
});
```

Cannot get anything to work. The javascript is being imported in a separate `header.html` file using php `echo` in the main `home.php`
 file.

```js
var html =
    '<body>\
      <div id="the-basics" class="bs-example" autofocus>\
          <input id="box" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" class="typeahead tt-input" placeholder="National Parks" type="text" autofocus>\
          <pre style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: pre; font-family: -apple-system; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: optimizelegibility; text-transform: none;" aria-hidden="true">a</pre>\
          <div style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;" class="tt-menu tt-empty">\
          <div class="tt-dataset tt-dataset-parks">\
          </div></div>\
      </div>\
    </body>';


function search(elem) {
      elem.outerHTML = html;
  }
```

```html
<p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-success search" onclick="search(this)">Get started today</button></p>
```

Comment: The body tag inside of html that's meant to be appended to a document makes me think that might be a problem.

Comment: Onclick won't work without the `body` wrapper